# Insert data row by row into anylogic database?

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a table `og_table` in the anylogic database that I load data into. From that table, I programmatically iterate on it through `selectResultSet`, and now I want to re-write those rows with some transformation into `new_table`. My plan then was just to run some `INSERT table ... values()` query into `new_table` that would write line by line.

However, I'm getting a little confused with documentation on which method to use. I see [modify()](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/connectivity/Database.html#modify), [InsertQuery()](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/database/InsertQuery.html), [Insert()](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/connectivity/Insert.html), etc. What's the difference between these methods?

Comment: You seem to be looking just at the raw API and not the help: there's a whole section there on DB queries with examples of INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT and DELETE (as in Artem's answer).

Comment: @StuartRossiter that helped so much, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert into the new table then this should work:

```java
insertInto(new_table)
          .columns(new_table.col1, new_table.col2)
          .values("Value 1", "Value 2")
          .execute();
```

You may also want to clear the `new_table` on model start up using this statement: `deleteFrom(new_table).execute();`